# AWS Fargate Containers with multiple open ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

### This is resolved, probably through one of the security group changes I made.

I have a container that spawns multiple programs. Each program listens on a unique port. It's a round-robin thing, and in a regular docker environment, we expose the possible range. Everything works just fine. Another container has an app that attaches to each of the little agents running in the first container. It's normal socket communications from there.

Now we're trying to migrate to Fargate. I've done the port mappings when creating the task definition, although there's a note that it might be getting ignored by Fargate. I'm seeing hints that Fargate really only lets you open a single port, referred to as the containerPort, and that's all you get. That seems... insane.

nmap shows the ports as filtered.

Am I just doing something wrong? Does anyone have hints what I should look at?

I read one paper that talked about a network load balancer. That seems like a crazy solution.

I don't want to spawn multiple containers for two basic reasons. First, we'd have to entirely rewrite the app that spawns these agents. Secondly, container startup time is way way too long for a responsive environment.

Suggestions of what I should look at?

Per a request, here's the relevant JSON, edited for brevity.

```
{
  "family": "agents",
  "executionRoleArn": "ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "agent-container",
      "image": "agent-continer:latest",
      "cpu": 256,
      "memory": 1024,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 22,
          "hostPort": 22,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 15000,
          "hostPort": 15000,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        {
          "containerPort": 15001,
          "hostPort": 15001,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        },
        ...
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "environment": [ ...  ],
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/ct-test-agents",
          "awslogs-region": "",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ct-test-agents"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "cpu": "256",
  "memory": "1024"
}
```

Comment: I have Fargate containers with multiple ports (`8080` and `8443`) working just fine. Can you post your settings maybe?

Comment: Okay, not sure what I did, but I fiddled with the security group, and I think the problem was one of my rules was wrong. It's not responsive.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be an issue with the security group attached to the service / task? Did you add rules that allow incoming traffic on the specified ports?

As you could reach the service with nmap I assume it is already publicly reachable and has a public IP address. But maybe the SecurityGroup does not allow access to the ports.

Comment: In case I was misunderstanding the security group, I traversed to it via the service, and then I added a rule that says "All TCP from 172.30.0.0/16". Nmap from 172-30-32-5 of "nmap -P0 -sT -p 22,80,15000 172.30.32.8" says all 3 ports are being filtered.

Comment: Nice to hear you resolved it. I fiddled around as well and couldn't replicate the problem, when I scanned the ports they were reachable.

Comment: Ya, I think I was being an idiot. I kept reading about port mappings, and it turned out my "open everything" rule in the security group was flawed.